# Wordpress as College Application System (Embark)

Tags: plugin-development, development-strategy

Anyone knows of any plugin or anyone has been using WordPress to serve as a College Application system similar to those by [Embark](http://www.embark.com/)?

If not, I'm looking for idea of using current plugins to accomplish this.

The system would allow students to create an account, upload their documents, check their status, invite people to submit a letter of recommendation.

The admin would then be able to manage those applications, change the status, notify the applicants.

Comment: Not quite what you're looking for, but you might want to take a look at [BuddyPress Courseware](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-courseware)

Comment: scribu took the words right out of my mouth -- I was going to suggest you take a look at BPC. However, it doesn't seem to be an applications framework as much as it is a Moodle/Blackboard competitor.

Answer (score 2):

I've not heard of any plugin that currently provides this functionality. This sounds like a perfect opportunity for custom WP development - either you hiring someone to code this for you (which could then be very useful to others desiring the same functionality), or someone in the WP community spontaneously filling a need ;-)

I've been customizing Wordpress lately to serve as a web app for all sorts of purposes I couldn't have imagined just a year ago. What you want might not exist yet, but it's totally doable...

Comment: custom WP is definitely first on my mind when I thought about this. I have no illusion there is a ready made solution out there but I thought I would see if I can adapt something out there to meet 80% of what I want.Audience for this kind of app is mostly colleges who already use Embark but want to consolidate with WP which they already use for their CMS. A rather small audience I would say. Speaking about custom dev, you have recommendation?

Comment: There are existing plugins that would take care of this piece or that piece, but nothing near 80% of what you've described. The workflow is quite different than typical wp usage. I just built an in-house asset management system for a media company that is similar, in that there are contributors who submit assets, editors who review, and a system for tracking the status of assets. I'd post the link, but it's a completely private site.

I'm available for custom development, drop me a message if you're interested...

Comment: Somatic. Yes, I'd like to see the AMS system you built. how do I contact you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to take user-submitted content and make something useful of it, [TDO Mini Forms (free)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tdo-mini-forms/) and [Gravity Forms (commercial, starts at $39)](http://gravityforms.com/) are very good places to start.  Simply create a form and start collecting responses.

Comment: Zamoose, exactly my first thought. I have GF developer licence so it's something I consider. But thinking a bit more, I would need a user registration where people can sign in to check their status, update documents so it's more than just an one-off form for people to drop things in. I see the use for GF at some stages in the process.

Comment: You could make custom post types with custom post statuses and allow people to log back in and check the status of their "post"...

Comment: Yeap, custom post sounds like a great use of that feature. What other user management system pluggin is a good candidate for this idea?